# Error after fixing unknown index in git

Tags: git

I'm still new to git and I've encounter the error `fatal: Unknown index entry format 692f0000`, I've encounter this after cloning my git so I tired to fix it with these commands:

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

But I receive the following errors below

```
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
error: corrupt loose object 
fatal: loose object is corrupt
```

How to solve it? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your current local repo has loose objects with damaged data, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403595/6309).

The first test would be to clone again the repo (in a new empty folder), to see if the original issue persists. Make sure to use the latest (2.17) Git version.
If the issue persists, then the problem might be at the source (the remote repo itself)